# Shortcut to activate/deactivate Outlook new mail notifications

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, batch-file, windows-registry, notifications

As I'm syncing calendars from/to O365/GSuite, I use a tool called [gSyncit](https://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit5/) which works perfectly fine and lets run Outlook in background mode to do the sync. Normally I want Outlook new mail notifications, but when I've finally some free time, I don't want it anymore (but still syncing appointments as mentioned before).

I'm using Win10x64/Outlook 365 and to deactivate the banner/sounds there is an option in the system Windows control-panel/notifications sections:
[image]

That works perfectly fine, but I search for a faster/smarter option to "toggle" (activate/deactivate) this option - like a script/batch file.

I've googled around but couldn't find a solution for this, so I'm hopping someone with more experience in this area could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not a faster/smarter option for this. You may try to post a new thread to a forum related to scipt or vba.